# Why can't my program read the GAME.INP file?

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPkfD.jpg)

I wrote code and encountered a problem
my code :

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

#include

using namespace std;

int main()

{

```
ifstream input("GAME.INP");

ofstream output("GAME.OUT");

if (input.fail())

{

    cout << 4 << endl;

}

int a;

input >>a;

output << a << endl;

input.close();

output.close();

return 0;
```

}